# How to parse multipart/related with GZIP compression in Node?

Tags: node.js, gzip, mime

We have an `express` server running in AWS Fargate which handles a standard called AS4 (`SOAP/XML`) with messages sent as `multipart/related`.

This has been working OK but now the standard is changing and compressed data shall be the new norm.

I've added a "raw" parser to express like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.pipe(concat(function(data){
    req.rawBody = data;
    next();
  }));
});
```

This gives me a Buffer of the body. I then do a `.toString('utf-8')` on teh Buffer data to get it into "parsable" data.

The incoming content-type is:
`Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/soap+xml"; boundary="uuid:5ae2a40e-3c76-4b15-bec4-11ffcaa5edb6"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml"`

A sample body (cut the mime part bodies though) may thus look like:

```
--uuid:5ae2a40e-3c76-4b15-bec4-11ffcaa5edb6
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Header><ns2:Messaging xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ebxml-msg/ebms/v3.0/ns/core/200704/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="true" wsu:Id="_f9ce22e6-c479-42af-9fdb-4091b838273b"></env:Envelope>

--uuid:5ae2a40e-3c76-4b15-bec4-11ffcaa5edb6
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <fee17328-8b1f-40c7-ae59-72adf2674f54@protocol-peppol-as42>
CompressionType: application/gzip
MimeType: application/xml

ù;h¶£[·튴£ȠtN|"ˑ֏֖‘؈»'²¨_„r©ºRɊРtY̯Ÿ\˒֑ϖ¹ӧ˜ʡ€ٕ؀&†vd±8OͲ n+Œ0;¡h7ٸaʈ��*QÀ’’ǎFʛX&܃㹠ö0x뻯⿓CUҕ{j:赍t
--uuid:5ae2a40e-3c76-4b15-bec4-11ffcaa5edb6--
```

Previously I just split the data as `utf-8` string on the boundary and was able to extract the different parts.

The problem is with the `application/octet-stream` data as it seems the data is "ruined" when I parse it out after the body has been read as `utf-8`.

Gunzip gives me a `incorrect header check` when trying to parse it out.

I've checked an made sure there are no extra line breaks or other other added characters.

Question then is, how can I parse/handle the binary/gzip mime part data and get it decompressed?

**EDIT 2021-11-15:**

Taking @RobertKawecki 's suggestions in comments I have successfully parsed out the "gzip" part as Buffer using `buffer-split`.

I left my original code for the "string" handling and run them both as separate copies of the payload.
Interestingly, if I log them both out to the console as "`string`" and as "`buffer.toString('utf-8')`" they look identical:
[image]

However, writing the two to file; The Buffer I write as "buffer" and the "string" as it is in UTF-8 there is a big size deferens, the "buffer" `.gz` file is `105 kb` while the "string" `.gz` file is `160 kb`.

None of the two still work though, neither as file nor to run `zlib.infalte` or `ungizip` on... Still `incorrect header check` from both of them...

I wonder if there is something else to it...
Looking at the Buffer it logs `<Buffer f9 3b 68 17 ee 95 ...` but a GZIP file should always start with `1f 8b` as far I read the specification... Could the `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` make it be coded in some other encoding that needs to be encoded before it is a "gzip" I wonder...?

**EDIT 2:**

Yes, just tested with POST'in a "clean" gzip file through and that produces a Buffer as `<Buffer 1f 8b 08 08 89 ...` so the `1f 8b` theory is correct!

Comment: Are you able to use a pre-existing multipart library to get the parts as Buffers?

Comment: @RobertKawecki, no, unfortunately I have not been able to find any mime library that can handle the message correctly...

Comment: This might help, assuming you can rely on being able to load the entire AS/4 message into memory: https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-split

Comment: Also maybe you can cheat a bit and use the same buffer-split to split the payload on CRLF (it's \r\n, right?). You might temporarily break the payload, but that's OK. Inspect the resulting chunks, check where the headers end, join the remainder back into one buffer -> that's your part's payload? Sounds like a poor man's parser, but hey, it's something.

Comment: Thanks @RobertKawecki; I did some additional testing and added an Edit to the original question...

Comment: Have you tried inflateRaw (which is gzip with no headers)? Protocol authors are pretty good at confusing these two.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertKawecki, but no go... :( got a new error as "invalid stored block lengths" with that...